# Split words with JavaScript, but skips some words before "\"

Tags: javascript, split

I have a string:

```
"a","b","c"
```

and I can split those words to:

```
a
b
c
```

using Javascript, but how about:

```
"a,","b\"","c\,\""
```

How do I get:

```
a,
b"
c,"
```

Comment: Do you have three strings or one string?

Comment: How are you splitting the string?

Comment: you cannot define "a","b","c" as one string.

Comment: Sure you can @imrantariq. Just add `'` around it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure if this is one string?  But if it is... and this is the only instance of it that you want manipulated, you could use this super convoluted way....

```
var a = '"a,","b\"","c\,\""';
var b = a.replace(/"/,'');
  //get rid of the first "
var c = b.lastIndexOf('"');
  //find the last "
var d = b.substring(0,c);
  //cut the string to remove the last "
var e = d.split('","');
  //split the string at the ","

for(var i="0"; i<e.length; i++){
    document.write(e[i] + '<br />');    
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/ceVG7/1/

Comment: Thanks, it is in one string, and your script did what i want, can you explain what it does?

Comment: @KongChunHo, I placed some comments in the code. Is there a particular piece or pieces I can give more info on?

Answer (score 0):

1. Split as you were
2. Replace any `\` in each resultant string, after the split (using `replace()`)

Comment: `String.replaceAll` in JavaScript?

Comment: `.replace(/\\/g,"")` will do. I actually think that these `\` in the question aren't a part of the string, but an escape character. The OP has to be more clear.

Comment: Can't!, Eg: "a\,","b","c", if i split ",", i will get: a\ " "b" "c"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define "a","b","c" as one string. If you have a string then,

The replace() method searches for a match between a substring (or regular expression) and a string, and replaces the matched substring with a new substring.

```
string.replace(regexp/substr,newstring)
```

The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.

```
string.split(separator, limit)
```

or
    var myString = "abc,efg";

```
var mySplitResult = myString.split(",");

mySplitResult[0] will be abc
mySplitResult[0] will be efg
```

Comment: This is a valid string: `'"a","b","c"'`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
'"a,","b\"","c\,\""'.replace(/^"|"$/g,'').split(/"\s*,\s*"/).join('<br/>')
```

that gives:

```
a,<br/>b"<br/>c,"
```

`<br/>` can be replaced by `\n` if the output is not HTML